# Office 365 for AD B2C app development team

Tags: azure, office365, azure-ad-b2c

What is the best practice to let my developers use Office 365 along their needs for Azure AD B2C app development?

I have an Azure AD B2C (assume using my custom domain *foobar.net* associated with *foobar.onmicrosoft.com*) and there are some B2C apps with social identity providers. Besides the consumer users with those social accounts, there are some administrators/developers who has certain privileges to manage resources in the directory.

However, these developers cannot be granted an Office 365 license through the domain because it is associated with the B2C directory. I can setup a trial subscription in the Admin Center with the domain but it tells me there is no valid licenses.

Then, how do I setup Office 365 for them? Setting up a new Azure AD (not B2C) directory (say *hogehoge.onmicrosoft.com*) and use it to manage Office 365 stuffs would be one solution. But it will make the developers has two user accounts for the AD and AD B2C directory (*user@hogehoge.onmicrosoft.com* and *user@foobar.net*) in order to manage respectively Office 365 affairs and B2C app development. Isn't there no way than this approach, looking a little weird to me?

EDIT: If a new directory is the best solution what should the name of the new directory usually be? Assuming that "foobar" is the name of the web service, "foobardev" for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to create a new directory, e.g. hogehoge.onmicrosoft.com, for access to all Microsoft online services, such as Office 365, and then invite users from this new directory as guests to the Azure AD B2C directory.

These guest users can be assigned in the Azure AD B2C directory to the Global Administrator role.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Just to clarify, in that case can they still use *foobar.net* as the domain of Office 365 (e.g., for their email domain) by adding the domain via the admin center?